# Select unique observation in group in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

How can i select unique observation in group.
Reproducible example.

```
mydata=structure(list(N = c(111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 
111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 112L, 112L, 112L), group = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "control group", class = "factor"), 
    char = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("bad", "good"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("N", 
"group", "char"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L
))
```

I need find only unique observation in N by char variable.
So `N` contains number of prisoner.
`char` contains good or bad behavior
So i must calculate total count of unique numbers of prisoners by good and bad category.
There are two group control and test, i just indicated control.
As we can see unique observations here 111 and 112 number.

Here output which i want

```
    number of unique   prisoners for control group
bad     2
good    2
```

How to perform it?

## Edit

```
mydata=structure(list(N = c(111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 
111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 
112L, 112L, 112L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 112L, 112L, 112L), 
    group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("control group", "test group"), class = "factor"), 
    char = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("bad", "good"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("N", 
"group", "char"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -28L
))
```

output divided by group

```
     control group test group
bad    2             2
good    2             2
```

Comment: `library(dplyr); mydata %>% group_by(char) %>% summarise(N_unique = n_distinct(N))`

Comment: @AntoniosK, i edited post , can you help me do it by group, see updated output

Comment: `library(tidyverse); mydata %>%
  group_by(group, char) %>%
  summarise(N_unique = n_distinct(N)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(group, N_unique)`

Comment: @AntoniosK, very well. last request. Is it possible to calculate for each value percentage 2/100=2% ; 2(2,00%)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `data.table` and `dplyr` packages:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

mydata %>% 
group_by(char) %>% 
summarise(Unique = uniqueN(N))
```

or for your final question:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

mydata %>% 
  group_by(char) %>% 
  summarise(Control = paste(uniqueN(mydata[mydata$group == 'control group',]$N),"(",
                           formatC(100 * uniqueN(mydata[mydata$group == 'control group',]$N)/100, format = "f", digits = 2),"%",")", sep = ""), 
            Test = paste(uniqueN(mydata[mydata$group == 'control group',]$N),"(",
                         formatC(100 * uniqueN(mydata[mydata$group == 'control group',]$N)/100, format = "f", digits = 2),"%",")",sep = ""))
```

Comment: uniqueN is part of the data.table package. I think. Please do correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Yes it is data.table, but i updated output, see edited post. How can i do it diveded by group

Comment: `library(data.table);
library(dplyr);

mydata %>% 
  group_by(char) %>% 
  summarise(Control = uniqueN(mydata[mydata$group == 'control group',]$N), Test = uniqueN(mydata[mydata$group == 'test group',]$N))`

Comment: @Maylo,  Is it possible to calculate for each value percentage 2/100=2% ; 2(2,00%)

Comment: @varimax simply add '/100' after each unique `library(data.table); library(dplyr); mydata %>% group_by(char) %>% summarise(Control = uniqueN(mydata[mydata$group == 'control group',]$N)/100, Test = uniqueN(mydata[mydata$group == 'test group',]$N)/100)`

Comment: @ Maylo Yes, but output bad    0.0200 0.0200 , and needed output 2(0.02) 
 2(0.02) /percentages in parentheses, I mean it. Then i accept your answer. Thank you ,

Comment: @varimax i've edited my above answer